# Change color of individual list items in AlexaTextList?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Is there a way to specify a color for the text in specific items in an AlexaTextList? In my example, I'd like to, based on a dynamic value in my lambda_handler, specific whether each text list item is red, yellow, or green. This is the template for the display:

```
{
"type": "APL",
"version": "1.8",
"license": "Copyright 2021 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.\nSPDX-License-Identifier: LicenseRef-.amazon.com.-AmznSL-1.0\nLicensed under the Amazon Software License  http://aws.amazon.com/asl/",
"theme": "dark",
"import": [
    {
        "name": "alexa-layouts",
        "version": "1.5.0"
    }
],
"mainTemplate": {
    "parameters": [
        "payload"
    ],
    "items": [
        {
            "type": "AlexaTextList",
            "headerTitle": "${payload.textListData.title}",
            "listItems": "${payload.textListData.listItems}",
            "secondaryText": "${payload.headlineTemplateData.properties.textContent.secondaryText.text}",
            "backgroundColor": "teal",
            "id": "covidList"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't with AlexaTextList.**

On APL, all component have the same [base properties](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-presentation-language/apl-component.html)
One of the property is called `style`, and you can apply a style with a color but [AlexaTextLists](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-presentation-language/apl-alexa-text-list-layout.html#list-items) doesn't acknowledge it.

```
{
    "redColor": {
        "values": [
            {
                "color": "red"
            }
        ]
    },
}

// in your components:
{ ... "style": "redColor", ... }
```

AlexaTextLists contains a list of [AlexaTextListItem](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-presentation-language/apl-alexa-text-list-item-layout.html) and doesn't acknowledge it as well.
**As of today, I recommend you to rely on Container and Text when you need more flexibility.**

```
{
    "type": "APL",
    "version": "1.8",
    "license": "Copyright 2021 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.\nSPDX-License-Identifier: LicenseRef-.amazon.com.-AmznSL-1.0\nLicensed under the Amazon Software License  http://aws.amazon.com/asl/",
    "theme": "dark",
    "import": [
        {
            "name": "alexa-layouts",
            "version": "1.5.0"
        }
    ],
    "mainTemplate": {
        "parameters": [
            "payload"
        ],
        "items": [
            {
                "type": "Container",
                "height": "100vh",
                "width": "100vw",
                "direction": "column",
                "alignItems": "center",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "Text",
                        "color": "red",
                        "text": "Text in red"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "Text",
                        "color": "blue",
                        "text": "Text in blue"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "styles": {}
}
```